# Restrict viewing the domain from subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My web site (mywebsite.name) is on a shared hosting and I have an addon domain (addondomain.eu) there. Since it is an addon domain on a shared hosting anyone can access my addon domain from addondomain.mywebsite.name

How can I restrict acessing to addondomain.mywebsite.name with htaccess?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661219/definitive-hide-add-on-domain-from-main-domain-htaccess/10664183

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684990/htaccess-login-on-multi-domain/10687561

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could use an urlrewrite to block access to the site from a specific url. but a better question is why would you want to? all you're doing is blocking legitimate visitors. a better option would be to redirect people back to your main domain.

Comment: Because the content becomes dublicate and I don't want mywebsite.name to be associated with my addondomain.eu domain. Also, I don't want to write PHP code to every page for redirection.