# htaccess login on multi domain

Tags: .htaccess, authentication

I've got a multi domain site (custom CMS) where all sites have the same documentroot. Depending on the url(domain) it will serve a different site. Having only 1 root they also have only 1 .htaccess

Now I want to protect 1 domain with a simple .htacess login ([like this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/))

How do I specify this login to 1 domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) support to protect only one of your domain. Here is the code that you need to put in your common `.htaccess` under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.subdomain\.com$ SECURED=yes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /your/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy         any
Order           allow,deny
Allow from      all
Deny from       env=SECURED
```

Above code will show basic auth popup only for `www.subdomain.com` while leaving other domains open.

Comment: +1 AFAIK, most LAMP Shared Hosting Providers load mod_setenvif :-)

Answer (score 1):

To enable an `.htpasswd` file you must use a specific subdirectory for that protected domain.  The trick is to use a subdomain-based internal redirect based on the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in the docroot `.htaccess` file, for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   =admin.example.com
RewriteRule   ^(?!admin).*   admin/$0               [L]
```

This will internally redirect any `htttp://admin.example.com/` references to the DOCROOT/admin subdirectory which can have its own `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files.

You may need to symlink and CMS entry scripts and subdirectories back to the shared instance.  [This](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-25) is how I did this for phpBB.